# Android suport libraries must use the exact same version

Tags: android

Please, what is wrong in this gradle code and how can I fixed it?

[image]

I think it is a suport libraries vesion incompatibility problem, but I do not know how to fixed it.

Below the complete content from app build.grade file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config_release {
            keyAlias 'xx'
            keyPassword 'xx'
            storeFile file('xx')
            storePassword 'xx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config_release
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "tier"

    productFlavors {
        pay {
            applicationId 'xx'
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            dimension "tier"
        }
        free {
            applicationId 'xx'
            versionCode 20
            versionName '2.11'
            dimension "tier"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.11.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
    freeImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'
}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the code still build ok despite the IDE error?

Comment: That problem generally is just a warning. It might occur because RecyclerView  dependency uses some different version in it self.

Answer (score 2):

You have to override each library with lower version showed in the hint, with the upper version. ( the same as showed in the hint, **27.1.1** in your case)

For example you have in the hint `com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0` :

So in the dependencies block add `'com.android.support:support:customtabs:27.1.1'` with the upper version **27.1.1** instead of **26.1.0** :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
```

And you repeat this until warnings go, you may have other warnings with other libraries after

Comment: Added **implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'** and the problem fixed.